# Work Integral and its derivation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

The work integral is something I saw long time ago and in completely understood it.

\begin{align}
W_{12} & =\int F(x)dx=m\int^{t_2}_{t_1}adx=m\int\left(\frac{dv}{dt}\right)dx=m\int\left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)dx\\
&=m\int\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)dv=\frac12\left(mv_2^2-mv_1^2\right)
\end{align}

which is clear as day.

But then i saw another version and i cannot follow it:

[image]

So my question is:

How did $$m\int\frac{d}{dt}[\dot{x}(t)]\dot{x}(t)dt$$ become $$\frac{m}{2}\int\frac{d}{dt}[\dot{x}(t)]^2dt$$

Where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from?

And how did that expression become the change in kinetic energy equation?

I'm sure this is a simple question but i havnt been able to find a solution online so im asking here. Thanks for the help

Comment: You are, I'd guess, happy with using the chain rule in this way: $\frac d{dt}y^2=2y\frac{dy}{dt}$. Put $y=\dot x(t)$ and re-arrange this as an integral .

Comment: It seems that you can edit mathematical equations with MathJax so please don't post images in place of text and mathematical equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're using the $2^{nd}$ principle of dynamics $\frac{d \mathbf{Q}}{dt} = \mathbf{F}$ to replace $\mathbf{F}$ with $\frac{d \mathbf{Q}}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(m\mathbf{v})$.

With the assumption $\dot m = 0$, you can further manipulate the expression $\mathbf{F} = m \frac{d \mathbf{v} }{dt} $, before writing the work integral as

$W = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{v} dt = m \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \underbrace{\frac{d \mathbf{v} }{dt} \cdot \mathbf{v}}_{=\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} \right)} dt = m \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{1}{2} |\mathbf{v}|^2 \right) dt = \int_{0}^{1} dT = T_1 - T_0$.

Answer (score 7):

Simple use of chain rule:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d \dot{x}^2}{dt}=2\dot{x}\frac{d\dot{x}}{dt}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Then isnt it :$m\int\frac{d}{dt}[\dot{x}(t)]\dot{x}(t)dt=m\int 2 \dot{x}\frac{d\dot{x}}{dt}dt$

Comment: Reverse your expression and multiply it by one half to start with the same conditions as the initial problem.

Comment: @JerryCohen you're confused about the quantity $\frac{d}{dt}$ is acting on, try writing it like this so it's more clear:  $\left(\frac{d\dot{x}(t)}{dt}\right)\dot{x}(t)$.